# menu image displays in android3.1 but not in 4.2

Tags: android

I have given my menu items with images.In android3.1 it displays menu with images but when i try the same coding in 4.2 the images are not displaying.Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_close"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
      android:title="close" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_signout"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
      android:title="Signout" />    
<item android:id="@+id/menu_cpc"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
      android:title="Change PIN" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_cpw"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="change password" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="Synchronize" /></menu>
```

Comment: images are probably too large for the menu. Make sure you are using a correct image size      ldpi 32 x 32 px
    mdpi: 36 x 36 px
    hdpi: 48 x 48 px
    xhdpi: 64 x 64 px

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google has removed it in the later versions.Icons no longer exist in [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

[This blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) says more about the same. So you should start using ActionBar instead.

Comment: can you please tell me,from which version menu icons can't be used?

Comment: Not sure. But AFAIK, from Icecream Sandwich

Comment: @SeshuVinay please give a quote from your link. I can't see that Google was removed in later versions.

Comment: No, this incorrect answer. Google offer use ActionBar as a replacement for menu, but it don't seems that it mandatory or this function removed.

Comment: It's not mandatory though. But They asked not to use Menus anymore and migrate to ActionBars instead. Read that blog to get more clarity on it.

Comment: But You can still use Menus. But icons are removed from Menu items.

Comment: Your answer misleading author and other developers. Menu is now available and icons too. Recheck before answer.

Comment: Can't you read this line in the blog "Not only should your apps stop relying on the hardware Menu button, but you should stop thinking about your activities using a “menu button” at all. "

Comment: Which means people should stop relying on Hardware Menu Button.

Comment: @deathember read the answer written by Commonsware guy.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908985/android-options-menu-icon-wont-display