# How to show list of icon with text in android action menu like image

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, action

[image: Menu picture]

I want to show a popup of option like the image on the click of action button( 3 ... icon).

I tried to do it by option menu but icon are not coming . Please suggest me how can I add icon as well.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="ui.dealroomcontent.DealRoomContentActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_view_details"
    android:title="View room details"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_details_normal"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_file"
    android:title="@string/action_create_file"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_createfolder_normal"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_folder"
    android:title="@string/action_create_folder"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_createfile_normal"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_upload_from_camera"
    android:title="@string/action_upload_from_camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_uploadcamera_normal"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_upload_from_gallery"
    android:title="@string/action_upload_from_gallery"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_uploadgallery_normal"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_upload_from_local"
    android:title="@string/action_upload_from_local"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dealroom_upload_normal"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: Try adding `app:showAsAction="never|withText"` inside `<item/>`. Is it working?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908985/android-options-menu-icon-wont-display

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_white"
        android:title="@string/action_more"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
                android:title="@string/action_settings"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                app:showAsAction="never" />

            <item ... />
        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

The ic_more_white is the icon of 3...
I wish this can help you.